# Find the sum of the series $\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}2+\frac{2}{3\cdot 4}2^2+\frac{3}{4\cdot 5}2^3+\cdots$ up to $n$ terms

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the following series up to $n$ terms

> $$\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}2+\frac{2}{3\cdot 4}2^2+\frac{3}{4\cdot 5}2^3+\cdots$$

Can someone please give any clue?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Just up to n terms

Comment: Partial fractions & telescope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the sum
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{(i+1)(i+2)} 2^{i}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now do partial fractions
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{i}{(i+1)(i+2)} =\frac{2}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now not that the powers of $2$ cause this sum to be telescoping, so
Rewrite the sum
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{(i+1)(i+2)} 2^{i}=\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+2}-1.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Yes ... You are right

Answer (score 3):

You are interested in the sum
$$
S_{N}\equiv\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{n}{\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)}2^{n}.
$$
As Donald suggests, you can use the partial fraction expansion
$$
\frac{n}{\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)}=\frac{2}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+1}
$$
to get
\begin{multline*}
S_{N}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{2}{n+2}2^{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n+1}2^{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)+1}2^{n+1}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n+1}2^{n}
=\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\frac{1}{n+1}2^{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n+1}2^{n}\\=\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\frac{1}{n+1}2^{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n+1}2^{n}=\frac{1}{N+2}2^{N+1}-\frac{1}{2}2^{1}
=\frac{1}{N+2}2^{N+1}-1.
\end{multline*}
From the above, it is clear that $S_{N}\rightarrow\infty$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Usiing telescopic sum
$$\sum_{n\geq1}^k\dfrac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)}2^n=\sum_{n\geq1}^k\left(\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+2}-\dfrac{2^{n}}{n+1}\right)=\dfrac{2^{k+1}}{k+2}-1$$

Comment: What is interesting is that, if we change $2^n$ to $a^n$, we end with a nightmare.

Comment: "The law in its majestic equality forbids the rich as well as the poor from stealing bread, begging and sleeping under bridges." Anatole France

Comment: Thanks for this quotation. Even being French, I did not knw it ! Cheers.